# Adding background-color to tag 'html' breaks z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index, less

I have the following styles defined in Less:

```
html {
  background-color: @playGreen;
}

body {  
  background-color: @background;
  background: url(../images/pattern/cream_dust.png) repeat 0 0;
}

.backStripe {
  background-color: @playGreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  z-index: -9;
}
```

In my Html code I have (irrelevant elements removed):

```
<html>
  <head>[...]</head>
  <body>
    <div class="backStripe">&nbsp;</div>
    [... other code ...]
  </body>
</html>
```

The idea of the given css is to set a fixed-size colour stripe as a background using a div with `position: absolute` and low `z-index`.

If I don't add any style to `html` (the tag itself) it works as expected. But if I add a `background-color` to `html` (to avoid gaps at the bottom on short pages) then the `backStripe` div is not shown anymore, it becomes completely hidden.

Any idea on why? How can I get the div to work along the `background-color` for `html`?

Comment: Add a semi-transparent background color `rgba()` on html and you'll see that `.backStripe` is still here... *below* the page.

Comment: @FelipeAls yes, my question is more on how to avoid it to get hidden

Comment: You could play with [`background-size`](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) (and multiple backgrounds on `body`) but that's compatible with IE9+. Here's the [ultimate tool for understanding z-index](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) by Thierry J. Koblentz and a reference article from MDN: [Understanding z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index). Your head will explode at least once ^^ Then [IE](http://caffeineoncode.com/2010/07/the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)... (head explodes a few times more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given `.backstripe` a *negative* z-index. That puts it **under** the html element. If the html element isn't transparent, it will conceal the `.backstripe` element.

Stick to positive z-indexes.